# Repair bad AHCI Driver Install

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, ahci

In a moment of madness I installed Intel RST drivers on my system and now Windows 7 (x64) no longer starts up.

Safe modes work, changing my driver controller to IDE in BIOS doesn't help.

Is there some way I can find out what the problem is and return my system to functionality, or is it time to reinstall Windows?  I tried a system restore  for the first time, but it appears to only roll back the registry.

Comment: I think you got the right approach here. Consider moving this comment into an answer, and accepting it, so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  It seems to have booted succesfully now. Booting in safe mode I uninstalled the Intel drivers, then rebooted safe again and removed all system devices related to ICH8 in device manager, Rebooted in IDE mode to safe boot and allowed Windows to detect the IDE devices, then rebooted again and in safe mode with device set to AHCI allowed Windows to detect them again.  A regular boot then worked.  Successive reboots have been clean also :)