# Switching RAID to AHCI without Windows Reinstall but Safe Mode does not open up

Tags: linux, windows, bios, safe-mode, ahci

I have an Acer Nitro 7 and I wanted to dual boot it with Zorin OS alongside Windows 10.
Since I have only got a 1 TB SSD which has its SATA Mode on RST premium with Optane, I used the answer given in this question to switch to AHCI mode:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041305/ubuntu-16-04-cant-see-my-ssd-partitions-when-installing-alongside-windows-10

I tried the Choice #2, and I believe the first command given -

> bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal

-is used to tell Windows to open in Safe mode by default as that's what the author says here :

> *"Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode"*

But in my case, after I entered the above command (it said the operation was executed successfully), and changed the SATA Mode to AHCI in BIOS, the laptop did not boot in Safe mode and showed "No boot device available".

I later changed the SATA Mode back to RST and when I tried restarting after closing the BIOS it automatically booted Windows 10 in Safe Mode.

So my question is, what do I do to make my laptop boot in Safe Mode after I change the SATA mode (the above mentioned command doesn't seem to be doing the work for me even though it executed successfully) to AHCI?

Or is there any other way I can switch to AHCI and proceed to install any Linux distro?

Comment: @Ramhound can you please elaborate what steps I needed to do in Windows before I proceed to do so in the firmware? There was nothing mentioned in the link I had provided. ( Thanks for the immediate reply! )

Comment: Disregard my last comment;  Those instructions you followed are the entire problem.  They are not correct.  Your SSD is SATA or NVMe?

Comment: You will want to follow the advice given in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/212932/repair-bad-ahci-driver-install?rq=1) after you make the appropriate backups of your system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to roll-back AHCI driver from iaStorA.sys --> msahci.sys Win7](https://superuser.com/questions/766661/how-to-roll-back-ahci-driver-from-iastora-sys-msahci-sys-win7)

Comment: @Ramhound My SSD is PCle NVMe SSS-RAID 0 (saw this from product description of my laptop in Acer site)

Comment: You realize by switching to ACHI you won't be able to use your Optane drive, right?  I would switch the drivers from within Safe Mode then switch the firmware settings per the instructions in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Ramhound I am a bit lost here, how am I supposed to switch the driver's from within the safe mode before I proceed with the firmware settings change?

Comment: You switch the driver from within Windows, then change it in the firmware, when the machine reboots to accept the firmware settings Windows should boot.  You should remain in Safe Mode until you know everything is working (the answers to the duplicate question explain the process).

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, so just to be clear: I should boot windows in Safe mode first. Then head over to Device Manager and perform the steps provided in the Choice #1 of the answer in the duplicate question (changing to Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller) and then change my SATA mode to AHCI in BIOS and reboot my laptop again. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Ramhound Update: so I booted in Safe mode, updated my Intel RST drivers to Microsoft Storage space controller under Storage Devices in Device Manager (as said in the duplicate question) and changed the SATA mode to AHCI. I ended up with a blue screen of death and a loop of automatic repair.

Comment: Well I did preface this suggestion that proper backups would be required.  However, Safe Mode should still work, as Safe Mode is suppose to resolve the driver issues.  Having done what I suggested myself, and having no problems, I am shocked it isn’t working for you.

Comment: I should have read the duplicate question more than once.  It was asking how to switch from ACHI to IDE.  You should be able to switch the firmware back to RAID then use a restore point to get your system working again.  While I feel bad I directed you in the wrong direction, I did specify, proper backups should be made before trying that solution.

Comment: @Ramhound Oh, it's alright lol, no need to feel bad here. I already took a backup before doing any of this. Would like to update now that the only way I could figure out for dual booting here was switching to AHCI, installing Zorin OS first by creating my own partition map and then later installing Windows from scratch (all while it's still in AHCI). A bit tedious as I also had to update grub after windows installation and had to install all the necessary drivers of my laptop in windows too. Would like to thank you for all your effort in helping me out, really appreciate it. :)